# Recharts: No display when looping twice inside the BarChart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I use Recharts to display my charts.
My data looks like that:

```
const data = [
      {name: 'day 1', supermarket1:{strawberry:4090, apple:3740} , supermarket2:{strawberry:6498, apple:1008}, supermarket3:{strawberry:4090, apple:3740}},
      {name: 'day 2', supermarket1:{strawberry:200, apple:768} , supermarket2:{strawberry:700, apple:876}, supermarket3:{strawberry:300, apple:932}}
]
```

I want to loop twice inside the barchart to display my data

I tried with just one loop inside the barchart and it worked perfectly but when I want to loop twice the display doesn't appear I don't know why

My code looks like that:

```
const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       {["supermarket1", "supermarket2", "supermarket3"].map((elt, index) =>{
         ["strawberry", "apple"].map((fruit, index2) =>{
         console.log(`${elt}.${fruit}`);
         return(
           <Bar
             key={index + index2}
             dataKey={`${elt}.${fruit}`}
             fill="#1f77b4"
           >
           </Bar>
         )
         })
       })}
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure Recharts accepts an object inside the data object? In their doc, I always see them like individual arrays, like this: ``const data = [
  {
    name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400,
  }]``

Comment: I think so coz the console log works and give correct results so the barchart accept the data like  it is now

Comment: Also when I loop only on supermarkets and use `${elt}. strawberry ` as a dataKey to the bar, the barchart is displayed perfectly

Comment: Yes. Because I think Recharts does not accept 2 elements. He expects one (for example when you do ``{elt}.strawberry``) , but you give `strawberry` and `apple` as an object

Comment: Can you explain more , I didn't get what you mean.
With one loop or even with two the barchart treats each bar by itself so there's no 2 elements that are treated both at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to map twice outside the BarChart and organize the data as wished in a third array to use it inside the BarChart.

```
const SimpleBarChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
  let keys= [];
  {["supermarket1", "supermarket2", "supermarket3"].map((elt, index) =>{
       ["strawberry", "apple"].map((fruit, index2) =>{
       keys.push(`${elt}.${fruit}`)
       })
       })}  
    return (
        <BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>

       {keys.map((key, index) =>{

       return(
       <Bar
         key={index}
         dataKey={`${key}`}
         fill="#1f77b4"
       ></Bar>
       )
       })}
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
})
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sud25m9L/)